# Matplotlib Unknown Property "headwidth" and "head_width"

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

I am trying to adjust the `headwidth` of an arrow in Matplotlib.

Here's a working code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
t = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,500)
y = np.sin(t)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t,y)

ax.annotate('', xy=(1, -1), xytext=(2, 0),
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', facecolor='black'))
```

[image: Sine plot with double-headed arrow]

And it plots a nice-looking double headed arrow as shown. Now when I want to alter the `headwidth` by doing:

```
ax.annotate('', xy=(1, -1), xytext=(2, 0),
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', facecolor='black',headwidth=10))
```

or

```
ax.annotate('', xy=(1, -1), xytext=(2, 0), 
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', facecolor='black',head_width=10))
```

The error returned is:

```
AttributeError: Unknown property headwidth
```

or

```
AttributeError: Unknown property head_width
```

Is there any way out?

Comment: What is ax? You miss a definition of ax in the code.

Comment: Thank you for the heads up! I just added it. Sorry to all for the missing piece!

Comment: arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->', facecolor='black',head_width=10)  is just a normal dictionary initialization. There should not be any error. I need your complete code to recur the problem.

Comment: Dear m170897017, it's already the complete code. T.T

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you specify an `arrowstyle` in your arrowprops dict, you get in instance of a FancyArrowPatch rather than YAArrow, which takes different keywords (but, you probably knew that given your attempt to use `head_width`).  What is unintuitive from the documentation is that when you specify the arrowstyle, which has default head settings, and etc., you modify those particular settings *in the arrowstyle string*.  This is the relevant line from the documentation [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/patches_api.html#matplotlib.patches.FancyArrowPatch) (emphasis mine):

> The arrowstyle describes how the fancy arrow will be drawn. It can be string of the available arrowstyle names, **with optional comma-separated attributes**, or one of the ArrowStyle instance.

If you change your dictionary to the following it will work:

```
arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='<->, head_width=10', facecolor='black')
```

Notice that the head_width specification is in the string following a comma after the style.  **Aside:** 10 is a rather large number for that one .... 0.5 might be better!

Comment: Wow great stuff, @Ajean! That is one *subtle* documentation! I couldn't get my head to it until you pointed it out. Now I can edit my arrows! Thanks for saving my day!!!!!

Comment: @Ajean I am having a similar error with `ncol` and `fancybox`. I could not find this information in the documentation, where can I find more information about related errors?

Comment: @mikey I presume that you mean `ncol` with `legend`, because there is no such thing as an `ncol` keyword for `FancyBboxPatch`, and I don't think there ever has been.  Just check the documentation for `legend` and make sure you are following it. Then if you still have issues, please ask a new question.